# How to repeatedly loop through list to assign values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I have two pandas data frames.  Within df1 I have a string column with a finite list of unique values.  I want to make those values a list, then loop through and append a new column onto df2. The value would loop through the list and then start over for the entire range of the second data frame.

```
df1
    my_value
0       A
1       B
2       C

df2
    color
0   red
1   orange
2   yellow
3   green
4   blue
5   indigo
6   violet
7   maroon
8   brown
9   black

What I want
    color          my_value
0   red             A
1   orange          B
2   yellow          C
3   green           A
4   blue            B
5   indigo          C
6   violet          A
7   maroon          B
8   brown           C
9   black           A

#create list
my_list = pd.Series(df1.my_value.values).to_list()

# create column
my_new_column = []

for i in range(len(df2)):
    assigned_value = my_list[i]

    my_new_column.append(assigned_value)

df2['my_new_column'] = my_new_column

return df2
```

The list index and range are differing lengths which is where I'm getting hung up.

This is super straight forward and I'm completely looking past the solution, please feel free to link me to another question if this is answered elsewhere.  Thanks for you input!

Comment: `df['new'] = (df.index % 3).map({0:"A",1:"B",2:"C"})`

Comment: Thank you!  I had been toying around with mod.  Your answer ultimately worked, just substituted for the column in the map rather than explicitly calling the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
#You can use zip with itertools.cycle() to cycle thru the smallest list/Series

df1 = pd.Series(data=['a','b','c'],name='my_values')
df2 = pd.Series(data= 'red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet','maroon','brown','black'], name='color')

import itertools

df2 = pd.concat([df2, pd.Series([b for a,b in zip(df2 , itertools.cycle(df1))], name='my_value')],axis=1)
df2


   color    my_value
0   red     a
1   orange  b
2   yellow  c
3   green   a
4   blue    b
5   indigo  c
6   violet  a
7   maroon  b
8   brown   c
9   black   a
```